# split one column to two in datatable c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-dataset

I have a dataTable with one column. I want to split into two column based on the column value

My datatable looks like below

```
Message
--------
PR-111 : test message
```

Output should be like below

```
PRNo    Message
------  -----------
PR-111  test message
```

I have tried to loop through the datatable and create the rows by splitting the column value  like below but that is not the efficient way .

```
 DataTable dt1Copy = new DataTable();

        dt1Copy.Columns.Add("PRNumber", typeof(string));
        dt1Copy.Columns.Add("Message", typeof(string));

        foreach (DataRow drNew in dt1.Rows)
        {
            string message = Convert.ToString(drNew["Message"]);
            var listData = message.Split(':').ToList();

            DataRow drCreated = dt1Copy.NewRow();

            drCreated["PRNumber"] = listData[0];
            drCreated["Message"] = listData[1];

            dt1Copy.Rows.Add(drCreated);

        }
```

Can anyone please suggest a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `linq` for this. In order for the `dataTable` to be usable in the `linq`, it must be `AsEnumerable()`

```
var r = dt1.AsEnumerable().Select(g =>new {PRNumber= g["Message"].ToString().Split(':')[0] ,
                           Message = g["Message"].ToString().Split(':')[1] }).ToList();
```

Comment: This is giving me a list but not a datatable